# Hibernate does not retrieve required records

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I cant retrieve required records from database, my classes are as following, I need to know which users' has inactive baskets.

```
Class Person {

}

Class User extends Person{
   private Set<Basket> basketlist;
}

Class Prof extends User {

}

Class Basket{
  private String active;
}


           Criteria cre = session.createCriteria(User.class, "user")
                    .createAlias("user.basketlist", "basket");
            ProjectionList pl = Projections.projectionList();
            pl.add(Projections.property("user.id").as("id"));
            cre.setProjection(pl);
            cre.add(Restrictions.eq("basket.active", null));
            IDs = cre.list();
```

Above code generates the following query (I am not sure why it includes Prof in this query and why it does not show users with inactive baskets)

```
select this_.id as y0_ from User this_ inner join Person this_1_ on 
this_.id=this_1_.id left outer join Prof this_2_ on this_.id=this_2_.id inner join 
User_basketlist basketl3_ on this_.id=basketl3_.User_id inner join basketlist 
basketl1_ on basketl3_.basketlist_id=basketl1_.id where basketl1_.active=?
```

Version of my Hibernate

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Which version of hibernate are you using?

Comment: question is updated , it is 4.2.1.Final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `NULL` it should be

```
Restrictions.isNull("basket.active")
```

Answer (score 1):

I am suspicious about `Restrictions.eq("basket.active", null)`. It is said to be fixed in `4.2.0.CR1` according to [this](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2951) which to me it means should be fine in `4.2.1.Final` but from query I can see that it is generating `where basketl1_.active=?` which is wrong. Try `Restrictions.isNull("basket.active")`